# How to enumare objects and total of them with the same key with another object in array js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm populing a pdf template with an array of employees, and now I need to count the number of employees working in a same department, I found a way to count the total of concurrences but I can't enumarate the employee working in the department and the total of them. Can you help me? Thanks!!!

For example, I have this array of objects

```
const employees = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "john",
    department: {
      id: 1,
    },
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Mike",
    department: {
      id: 3,
    },
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Leona",
    department: {
      id: 1,
    },
  },
   {
    id: 1,
    name: "Lara",
    department: {
      id: 1,
    },
  },
];
```

Result Expected:

```
    const employees = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "john",
    department: {
      id: 1,
    },
    totalForDeparments: "1/3",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Mike",
    department: {
      id: 3,
    },
    totalForDeparments: "1/1",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Leona",
    department: {
      id: 1,
    },
    totalForDeparments: "2/3",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Lara",
    department: {
      id: 1,
    },
    totalForDeparments: "3/3",
  },
];
```

Comment: You could try [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you group by the department.id - then you can iterate the original array adding the correct indexes.

```js
const employees = [{id:1,name:"john",department:{id:1}},{id:1,name:"Mike",department:{id:3}},{id:1,name:"Leona",department:{id:1}},{id:1,name:"Lara",department:{id:1}},];

var grouped = employees.reduce(function(agg, item) {
  agg[item.department.id] = agg[item.department.id] || {
    count: 0,
    current: 0
  }
  agg[item.department.id].count++;
  return agg;
}, {});

employees.map(function(item) {
  var data = grouped[item.department.id]
  data.current++;
  item.totalForDeparments = data.current + "/" + data.count

})

console.log(employees)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important}
```

Comment: should be spelled `totalForDepartments`

Comment: How did you do this? You are a genius! I don't know how to thank you, thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks thanks!!!

Comment: oh it's just my 3rd "group array of objects by key using reduce"... for today

Comment: My god It's not working in Reactjs!!! "Cannot add property totalForDeparments , object is not extensible"

Comment: I think I could fix it cloning the array of objects using lodash "let clonedEmployees = cloneDeep(employees"